Decimal problem during series/list conversion
I get a problem of decimal when I try to convert a Pandas Series to a Python list, it arises when I manipulate floating numbers.
I didn't expected that and got tricked by this silent problem when I tried to intersect two lists and got a wrong behaviour.
I tried to solve it with decimal package, but didn't work. Then I managed to solve it by forcing to round the value to 2 decimals but I'm not really happy with it. Is there a way to avoid this problem ? Or are we forced to round the list values everytime ?
Here is a minimal example to reproduce the problem:

# --- THE PROBLEM

import pandas as pd

# Create a Pandas Series
series1 = pd.Series([0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8])

# Create a new Series from the original
series2 = series1 + 0.1

# Convert the series to a list
list_from_series1 = series1.tolist()
list_from_series2 = series2.tolist()
list_from_series3 = list(series2)

# Show output
print(list_from_series1)   # no problem
print(series2)             # no problem
print(list_from_series2)
print(list_from_series3)


# --- ATTEMPT TO SOLVE IT WITH DECIMAL PACKAGE
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 2
print(list_from_series3)


# --- FORCE IT
import numpy as np
list_from_series3 = np.around(np.array(list_from_series3),2)
print(list_from_series3)

OUTPUT
[0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8]
0    0.3
1    0.5
2    0.7
3    0.9
dtype: float64
[0.30000000000000004, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9]
[0.30000000000000004, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9]
[0.30000000000000004, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9]
[0.3 0.5 0.7 0.9]


This problem has nothing to do with pandas. It's caused by the fact that reals (floating point numbers) have limited precision in any implementation and that most reals can only be approximated. For instance: 0.1 + 0.2 == 0.30000000000000004 != 0.3

As mudskipper has commented, this is not a pandas problem. Its a floating point number calculation issue. you are not seeing the decimals when calling for the series because of display options.
I believe this stack overflow post might clarify that...

As others pointed out, this is caused by Python, not Panda.
decimal would be a way to handle it, but you need to convert each value to a Decimal.
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

# Create a Pandas Series
series1 = pd.Series([Decimal('0.2'), Decimal('0.4'), Decimal('0.6'), Decimal('0.8')])

# Create a new Series from the original
series2 = series1 + Decimal('0.1')

